# Shouldn't we make "tether" a synonym for the "tethering" tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

Step-by-step tag clean-up, part 3 :)

"tether" should become a synonym for "tethering"..., right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done :)